# Trying to find what is wrong with my code

Tags: python-3.x

Here I am trying to devolope a game.

***Anyone please explain why boolean value of the variable `win` is not updating if `Board` value changes***

Here is the code..

```py
Board = {'1':'1','2':'6','3':'7',
         '4':'2','5':'5','6':'8',
         '7':'3','8':'4','9':'9'}

Win = Board['1'] == Board['2']== Board['3']=='X' or Board['4'] == Board['5'] == Board['6'] or Board['7'] == Board['8'] == Board['9'] or Board['1'] == Board['5'] == Board['9'] or Board['3'] == Board['5'] == Board['7'] or Board['1'] == Board['4'] == Board['7'] or Board['2'] == Board['5'] == Board['8'] or Board['3'] == Board['6'] == Board['9'] 
turn = 'X'
print(Win)

for i in range(9):
    a = str(input('Enter choice {}: '.format(turn)))
    Board[a] = turn
    turn = 'Y' if turn == 'X' else 'X' 
    if Win:   #Here I am expecting Win to be True but it is actually False
        print('Win')
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: You need to declare `Win` again inside the loop.

Comment: You're only setting the value of `Win` once at the beginning. No, it will not update in response to changes in `Board`. You need to explicitly assign a new value to `Win` again after the `Board` has changed.

Comment: Can you explain why the varibale Win will not get updated?

Comment: Because this is imperative programming. The computer does exactly what you tell it to when you tell it to. `Win = ...` evaluates the right hand side of that assignment *right there* and assigns the result of it to `Win`. This does not implicitly get reevaluated afterwards. This isn't mathematical notation, where `=` establishes a relationship. There are other languages that do that kind of thing, but not imperative ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one static boolean value that is unmodified as you "play the game"

Instead, define a function that inspects the state of the board

```
def isWin(board):
    return board['1'] == board['2']== board['3']=='X' or ...
```

Then use that within the game loop

```
Board[a] = turn
turn = 'Y' if turn == 'X' else 'X' 
if isWin(Board):
    ... 
    break  # stop the game
```

Comment: Can you explain why the 'Board' variable is not updating outside the function ?

Comment: Your original question has no functions. And my answer never modifies the dictionary inside the isWin function, so I'm not sure I understand the question.